# How do i delete an arc from a graph?

Tags: c++

I have this structure for my graph:

```
struct vertex{
    string nameV;
    string type;
    int serial;
    string core;
    string user;
    struct vertex *sigV;
    struct arc *subListArcs;
    vertex(string n,string t, int s, string c,string u){
        nameV=n;
        type=t;
        serial=s;
        core=c;
        user=u;
        sigV=NULL;
        subListArcs=NULL;
    }
    bool visited;
}*graph;

struct arc{
    int megabyte;
    string destination;
    struct arc *sigA;
    arco(int m, string d){
        megabyte=m;
        destination=d;
        sigA=NULL;
    };
};
```

and this function that finds the arc inside sublistArcs in every vector:

```
void deleteArc(string origin, string destination){
    struct vertex *tempV=graph;
    while(tempV!=NULL){
        if(tempV->nameV == origin){
            struct arc *tempA=tempV->subListArcs;
            while(tempA!=NULL){
                if(tempA->destination==destination){

                    tempA=NULL;

                    return;
                }
                tempA=tempA->sigA;
            }
        tempV=tempV->sigV;
        }
    }
}
```

My idea was to use tempA=NULL, to delete it, but it wasnt that easy. 
Does someone knows how to delete an arc?

Comment: Learn to use C++ [containers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) and [<memory>](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/memory) notably [std::shared_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr)

Answer (score 0):

since your list of arcs is *singly linked*, you need not only to find the target arc to delete, but also its previous in the list, because when you remove the target you need to link the previous to the next.

```
        struct arc *tempA = tempV->subListArcs;
        struct arc *prevA = NULL; // <------- will track previous arc
        while(tempA != NULL){
            if(tempA->destination==destination){
                // caught
                if(prevA == NULL){  // arc to remove is first in list
                    tempV->subListArcs = tempA->sigA; // next becomes first in list
                } else {
                   prevA->sigA = tempA->sigA; // <--- link previous to next
                }
                // now delete the arc removed from list, and return
                delete tempA;
                return;
            }
            prevA = tempA;      // <-- keep track of the previous
            tempA=tempA->sigA;
        }
```

p.s. this code style using raw pointers and linked lists is very much C-style, it does not match modern C++. Think of using the standard library's containers for your data structures.